# Create a group of UIButtons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a project that contains 35 identical buttons (with black background and gray border) located one beside the other (5 in the first row, then five more in the bottom, fill up my whole screen of iphone).

The way in which I am putting the edges is:

```
    button1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    button1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

    button2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    button2.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

    button3.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    button3.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];

    ....

    button35.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    button35.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
```

Imagine how many lines of code were repeated and that to me does not mean a good thing, in this case would like to know how can I minimize it? it is possible to group all the buttons in one?

Comment: You can combine them to array and configure in the loop

Comment: try with for loop/collection view/UITableview

Comment: You could also subclass the buttons with this happening in their init

Comment: are the buttons programmatically made or do you have them layed out in your user interface as properties?

Comment: I  out in your user interface as properties @Mediyum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a..

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonCollection;
```

and connect all your buttons to this.

Then define your attributes in your user interface like this (screenshot is of my buttons, so set your properties how you wish)

[image]

Or cycle through your buttonCollection with this..put this in your viewDidLoad

```
for(UIButton *button in buttonCollection){
            //capture frame
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
            button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly not the best way to do it but the idea is that a UIButton is inherits from a UIView.

So you can get your button Array by looking for the subviews of the view with the buttons on.

Use fast enumeration on the array to check the class is UIButton and make the changes.

```
NSArray * arr = _myView.subviews;

    for (UIView * button in arr) {
        NSLog(@" button %@",  button);
        if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            // UIButton* thisButton =button;
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
            button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
        }
    }
```

My quick test does work here.

But as I say I cannot say if this is a good idea to do it this way,. Hopefully comments will educate me if there are pit falls..

Comment: This answer demonstrates a loop, and in contrast to @Alok's answer, the code is pertinent to the question, looping existing buttons and setting the properties that are discussed in the OP.  The one caution I'd add is that this will change every button subview, even those not in the grid.  +1

Comment: Good point on the caution. I did think about that but the op said the button grid fills the whole screen. They could add a tag to the buttons and also check against that.

Answer (score 0):

for loop with array sample is some thing like this:

```
NSArray *keyPadImage=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"keypad1-3.1.png",@"keypad2-3.1.png",@"keypad3-3.1.png",@"keypad4-3.1.png",@"keypad5-3.1.png",@"keypad6-3.1.png",@"keypad7-3.1.png",@"keypad8-3.1.png",@"keypad9-3.1.png",@"keypad-dot-3.1.png",@"keypad0-3.1.png",@"keypad-x-3.1.png",nil];

int height;
int count = [keyPadImage count];
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    height=i/3;
    UIButton *keyPad=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15+(i%3)*92, 72+(height*75), 89, 72)];
    [keyPad setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[keyPadImage objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [keyPad addTarget:self action:@selector(modifyTotalAmount:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [keyPad setTag:(i+1)];

    [self.view addSubview:keyPad];
}
```

Thanks